# How to iterate over only specific keys from a JSON array object using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, nested

I am having a below json array and now I need to iterate over the json object to retrieve two values of fields ServicePort And ServiceAddress and form a final output as {"MyIp" : "http://IP:Port"} from my json array object.

```
var bodyObject = [
    {
        "ServiceAddress": "10.X.X.125",
        "ServiceConnect": {},
        "ServicePort": 80
    },
    
    {
       
        "ServiceAddress": "10.X.X.126",
        "ServiceConnect": {},
        "ServicePort": 80
    }
];
```

I have tried as below to iterate

```
for (var key in bodyObject ) {
       if (bodyObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          console.log(bodyObject[key].ServiceAddress);
          console.log(bodyObject[key].ServicePort);
       }
       }
```

How can I form a output final output like {"MyIp" : "http://IP:Port"} from my json array object each hitting giving me a diffrent Ip's from my above JSON list dynamically. Can someone help on this please

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Well, just concate the IP and the port strings. You already shown us you know how to get them

Comment: Thanks @Cid, can you help me concatenating it in json response format please

Comment: Everything you need is in [T.J. Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70108828/8398549)

Answer (score 3):

I **think** you're asking how to create a new array with a single object with a `MyIp` property whose value is the combination of `ServiceAddress` and `ServicePort`. `map` is the idiomatic way to do that, perhaps with some destructuring to pick out the properties from each object and a template literal to build the resulting string:

```
const result = bodyObject.map(({ServiceAddress, ServicePort}) => {
    return {MyIp: `http://${ServiceAddress}:${ServicePort}`};
});
```

or with a concise-form arrow function:

```
const result = bodyObject.map(({ServiceAddress, ServicePort}) =>
    ({MyIp: `http://${ServiceAddress}:${ServicePort}`})
);
```

(You need the `()` around the object literal because otherwise it looks like the full function body form of arrow function to the parser.)

Live Example:

```js
const bodyObject = [
    {
        "ServiceAddress": "10.X.X.125",
        "ServiceConnect": {},
        "ServicePort": 80
    },
    
    {
       
        "ServiceAddress": "10.X.X.126",
        "ServiceConnect": {},
        "ServicePort": 80
    }
];

const result = bodyObject.map(({ServiceAddress, ServicePort}) =>
    ({MyIp: `http://${ServiceAddress}:${ServicePort}`})
);

console.log(result);
```

That has a fair number of newish JavaScript features in it, so just for clarity here's a version without destructuring or a template literal:

```
const result = bodyObject.map(element => {
    return {MyIp: "http://" + element.ServiceAddress + ":" + element.ServicePort};
});
```

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder, I have tried to use the above snippet but it makes my function undefined error as "ReferenceError: 'test' is not defined". test is my function name here. Can you please let me know why and how go past this please

Comment: @Mahesh - I can't help you with code I can't see. The code above won't suddenly make your function not defined (except on IE11, because of the arrow function -- but IE11 is obsolete).